# Everytime i need to pass the token of current logged in user in laravel 5.5 and using jwt auth

Tags: php, laravel, token

I having problem that when user logged in i get a token and i am building apis and that token i need to pass on every request in postman:

My Response when i got current logged in user;

```
{
"token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwOi8vMTI3LjAuMC4xOjgwMDAvYXBpL2xvZ2luIiwiaWF0IjoxNTIzMjY5OTUxLCJleHAiOjE1MjMzMDU5NTEsIm5iZiI6MTUyMzI2OTk1MSwianRpIjoiSlNXa0hPbGxvOWdQNnRkNCIsInN1YiI6MiwicHJ2IjoiODdlMGFmMWVmOWZkMTU4MTJmZGVjOTcxNTNhMTRlMGIwNDc1NDZhYSJ9.Dt9fLL4d1mgwU7LMCNOeBoITs4Q0mAIeG07aCjRgaNM",
"currentUser": {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Shahzad Hussain Shah",
    "email": "shahzad.hussain@vaivaltech.com",
    "created_at": "2018-04-09 10:22:18",
    "updated_at": "2018-04-09 10:22:18"
       }
     }
```

and this token i need to pass everytime and if shut down my pc and on again then i have to login my user again so that i got a new token and then i can start my work with that token:

Here i want to avoid this token and when my website comes to live what will be the solution of tproblem:

When i used Auth::user()->id; it says trying to get property of non object then i need to pass the token: but here i want i just used Auth::user(); and it should pick id of current logged in user:

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Is this token changes everytime means what is lifetimespan of token?

Comment: yes this token changes everytime if logged in same user again after 1 minute this token changed! thats problem i am having... and if some new user come and sign up i will get a new token and then this token i need to pass again

Comment: you only generate the token once and use the same token to do authenticated calls till the token expires. Every time you call login user, you will get different token each time. Are you aware of this?

Comment: i am sure i get a different token when i call a login user again any doubt?

Comment: that's normal. Every time you call Login function, you will get new tokens. The idea is to do Login function once and save the token somewhere and use the same token to make other calls.

Comment: I'm using laravel passport and i'm also got new token every time after same user login, but i don't need to pass everytime different token to get any other apis. Only 1 token i can use to make other api calls! I'm also use laravel passport first time. So, i'm pretty new with passport. Doesn't know why this happens. I'm using this docs anyway: https://medium.com/techcompose/create-rest-api-in-laravel-with-authentication-using-passport-133a1678a876

Comment: so what should i do?should i go with passport?

Comment: See, i don't suggest you that you go with passport, but as i used passport, there's no need to send new token every time after same user login to make other api calls! So, you can use it OR test it for your reference. If your issue might be fixed using Laravel Passport, then it's great!!

Comment: you can use local storage to persist user auth state